# How to Mock Spring JDBCTemplate execute method in Junit Test case

Tags: java, junit, mockito, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

When I am executing the second test testExecute_noException, still its returning null pointer exception. For first test is returning null pointer exception is valid, but for the second test I need to continue with the next lines tests. Please refer more details in below.

---

**Actual Code:**

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepContribution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.ChunkContext;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.Tasklet;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class SimpleQueryExecutorTasklet implements Tasklet {

    private DataSource dataSource;
    private String sql;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    public void setSql(String sql) {
        this.sql = sql;
    }

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
        new JdbcTemplate(this.dataSource).execute(this.sql);
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
}
```

---

**Test Code:**

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepContribution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.ChunkContext;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SimpleQueryExecutorTaskletTest {

    @InjectMocks
    SimpleQueryExecutorTasklet simpleQueryExecutorTasklet;

    @Mock
    StepContribution stepContribution;

    @Mock
    ChunkContext chunkContext;

    @Mock
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Mock
    DataSource dataSource;

    String sql="select * from abc;";

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        simpleQueryExecutorTasklet.setDataSource(dataSource);
        simpleQueryExecutorTasklet.setSql(sql);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(JdbcTemplate.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(jdbcTemplate);
    }

    @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
    public void testExecute() throws Exception {
        simpleQueryExecutorTasklet.execute(stepContribution,chunkContext);
    }

    @Test
    public void testExecute_noException() throws Exception {
     Mockito.doNothing().when(jdbcTemplate).execute(Mockito.any(String.class));
        simpleQueryExecutorTasklet.execute(stepContribution,chunkContext);
        // Here will write some assertions
    }
}
```

---

**Exception log from Junit execution:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
                at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:390)
                at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:428)
                at com.xxxxxx.api.accel.operations.SimpleQueryExecutorTasklet.execute(SimpleQueryExecutorTasklet.java:29)
                at com.xxxxxx.api.accel.operations.SimpleQueryExecutorTaskletTest.testExecute_noException(SimpleQueryExecutorTaskletTest.java:61)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
                at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
                at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
                at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
                at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
                at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
                at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
                at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
                at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
                at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
                at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
                at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
                at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
                at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
                at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
                at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
                at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
                at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
                at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
                at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
                at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: I observed that in the main class execute method we are always creating new jdbc template (new JdbcTemplate(this.dataSource).execute(this.sql);) and this might be the reason its not taking the mock of jdbc template.

Comment: I suggest using `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` in your test class. With that, you don't have to specify the `runWith` annotation and some other things. It makes mockito run smoothly in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found that the issue is with the main class method. We are creating new JDBC template every time (not injecting) and thats the reason its failing though we are mocking the JDBC template in the junit method. After the changing main class the code to inject the jdbc template, it started working.

**Actual Code:**

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepContribution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.ChunkContext;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.Tasklet;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class SimpleQueryExecutorTasklet implements Tasklet {

    private DataSource dataSource;
    private String sql;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }
    public void setSql(String sql) { this.sql = sql; }

    public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) { this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate; }
    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate () {
        return this.jdbcTemplate == null ? new JdbcTemplate(dataSource) : this.jdbcTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
        getJdbcTemplate().execute(this.sql);
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
}
```

**Test code:**

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepContribution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.ChunkContext;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertSame;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SimpleQueryExecutorTaskletTest {

    @InjectMocks
    SimpleQueryExecutorTasklet simpleQueryExecutorTasklet;

    @Mock
    StepContribution stepContribution;

    @Mock
    ChunkContext chunkContext;

    @Mock
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Mock
    DataSource dataSource;

    String sql="select * from abc;";

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        simpleQueryExecutorTasklet.setDataSource(dataSource);
        simpleQueryExecutorTasklet.setSql(sql);
        //PowerMockito.whenNew(JdbcTemplate.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(jdbcTemplate);
    }

    @Test
    public void testExecute() throws Exception{
        simpleQueryExecutorTasklet.setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);
        RepeatStatus repeatStatus = simpleQueryExecutorTasklet.execute(stepContribution,chunkContext);
        assertNotNull(repeatStatus);
        assertSame("FINISHED", repeatStatus.toString());
    }
    @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
    public void testExecute_Exception() throws Exception{
        simpleQueryExecutorTasklet.setJdbcTemplate(null);
        simpleQueryExecutorTasklet.execute(stepContribution,chunkContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong runner. If you are using PowerMock, you need `PowerMockRunner`. Also, you need to use `@PrepareForTest` when you tap into object creation.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(JdbcTemplate.class)
public class SimpleQueryExecutorTaskletTest {
...
}
```

Comment: If you observe the test code, first I am mocking the JDBC template and returning the same mock jdbc template from execute method in the before section and using that same mock in the test  method.

Though I am mocking the JDBC template class and jdbc template execute method, why its going inside method jdbc template execute method and returning true ?

Comment: @Somu Sorry, I overlooked that. Check the updated answer.

Comment: I tried with your updated code, still it didn't work. I found that the issue with the main class method we are creating new JDBC template every time (not injecting) and thats the reason its failing though we are mocking the JDBC template in the junit method. After the changing main class the code to inject the jdbc template, it started working. Thanks for your response !!

Comment: The whole point of using powermock is that it can intercept new object creation, so that you can create a test without modifying the class under test. Having said that, injecting jdbc template is a good idea (this was the first version of my answer). Also, you don't need to inject data source when you inject jdbc template

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class DaoImplTests{

    @Autowired
    private Dao dao;

    @Mock
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Test
    public void testUsingMockito() {
        try {
            User mockedUserInfo = new User();
            //setters
            mockedUserInfo.setXXX;
            mockedUserInfo.setYYY;

            Mockito.when(((JdbcDaoSupport)dao.getTemplate())).thenReturn(jdbcTemplate);
            Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(Object[].class),
                    Mockito.any(RowMapper.class))).thenReturn(mockedUserInfo);
            User userInfo = dao.getUserInfo("");
            Assert.assertNotNull(userInfo);
            Assert.assertEquals(mockedUserInfo.getXXX(), userInfo.getXXX());
            //few more assertions
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Assert.fail(" : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If I use SpringJUnit4ClassRunner class, i am getting different error ContextConfiguration not found for class SimpleQueryExecutorTaskletTest
TestExecutionListeners is not present for class SimpleQueryExecutorTaskletTest: using defaults.Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener464bee09] to prepare test instance [com.mastercard.api.accel.operations.SimpleQueryExecutorTaskletTestf6c48ac]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Comment: I tried with your updated code, still it didn't work. I found that the issue with the main class method we are creating new JDBC template every time (not injecting) and thats the reason its failing though we are mocking the JDBC template in the junit method. After the changing main class the code to inject the jdbc template, it started working. Thanks for your response !!